# Making the input function of Python into C

Tags: python, c, input, cs50

There is this library called `<cs50.h>` in a sandbox I use for program building. It has input functions to get a certain data type, where the format would be `get_(data type)`.

So I tried experimenting a `get_int()` function in Python:

```
def get_int(text):
    result = int(input(text))
    return result
```

And it works! So I tried to experiment the input function of Python by writing it in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

char *input(char *text);

int main() {
    char *name = input("What's your name? ");
    printf("Hello, %s.\n", name);
}

char *input(char *text) {
    printf("%s", text);
    char *result = get_string("");
    return result;
}
```

It works, though the only problem is that it can only take strings, and I don't know how to get which variable to be used. So how do I get the needed data type?

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent function in C that converts a string into an integer is [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/), from `stdlib.h`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int get_int(char *text);

...

int get_int(char *text) {
    char *input_str = input(text);
    return atoi(input_str);
}
```

That said, why bother, when you could just use [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) from `stdio.h`, which is as flexible for input as `printf()` is for output, and more flexible than python's `input()` in general?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int get_int(char *text);

...

int get_int(char *text) {
    printf("%s", text);
    int result;
    scanf("%d", &result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `scanf()` is a little tricky for me, especially with the way how it gets input. I didn't say I want a `get_int()` function but okay, I guess that could help me get an understanding on how data type swap works.

Comment: `scanf()` ceases to be scary as soon as pointers themselves cease to be scary. You just tell it what you want, and hand it the locations for it to put the input (`&result`, a pointer to an area of memory for it to overwrite with the input). In this case, you don't even have to worry about allocating or freeing memory, since C is return-by-value.

Comment: Okay, I guess that helps.